# How to avoid retrieve entire stored field from solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'm using sunspot and solr for a rails app to search ebook contens, for highlight feature I have to set the ebook_content as a stored filed, every time I queried solr for result, it sends back the entire document content about the book, which makes the query very slow.

How could I only get the result without the stored field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`fl` parameter of Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) allows you to specify which fields you want returned in the result. If you had fields `id, title, ebook_content`, then you could use `fl=id,title` to omit the `ebook_content` field. I don't think there's support in Solr for getting all fields *except* one (e.g. `-ebook_content`).

**Update**

If you don't want to return the field in the normal results, but still want [highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) on that field, exclude the field as I described above, then turn on the highlighter:

```
hl=true
```

set the field(s) which should be highlighted:

```
hl.fl=ebook_content
```

and set the size of the highlighting fragment (in characters):

```
hl.fragsize=50
```

your finished query looks something like this:

```
?q=search term&fl=id,title&hl=true&hl.fl=ebook_content&hl.fragsize=50
```

Comment: if I take ebook_content out of fl, I cannot get the highlight, any special query here?

Comment: ... you want highlighting on `ebook_content` but you don't want to return it as part of the result? I don't really understand...

Comment: I mean, I only need the highlight part of ebook_content, not the entire content of the field, it sometimes has 100k data to transfer

Comment: Okay, so you want an excerpt from `ebook_content`, in the location that the highlighting would occur; correct?

Comment: Sorry about my late response, yes, I tested this and it works, thank you~