# Show a portion of searchable text in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing

I have indexed very large documents, In some cases these documents has 100.000 characters. Is there a way to return a portion of the documents (lets say the 300 first characters) when i am querying "Solr"?. Is there any attribute to set in the schema.xml or solrconfig.xml to achieve this?
I have tried many things but nothing worked.

Thank you in advance,

Tom

Comment: I see you're cross-posting to the `solr-user` mailing list. When you receive good answers there, please post them here as well. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a preview, you need to use a `copyField` and specify `maxChars`:

```
<copyField source="searchedField" dest="previewField" maxChars="300" />
```

Then display `previewField` instead of `searchedField` in your results.

I'm assuming you **do not** want normal search highlighting. If you do, just use the built-in [highlighting parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) with `hl.fragsize` as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10306407/320220).